# Proof verification: Proving that any positive real number has a square root using the Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am tasked with using the intermediate value theorem to prove that every positive real number $y\in\mathbb{R}$ has a square root, using the intermediate value theorem (as the title suggests). For this purpose, consider the function $f(x)=x^2$. We note that $f(0)=0$, and therefore $f(0)\leq y$, since $y$ is a positive value. We note also that $f(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$. That is, $\forall m\in\mathbb{R}$, $\exists x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)>m$. For this reason, pick $m>y$, then we have that $\exists x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)>m$. Therefore $f(0)\leq y<f(x_0)$, and, since $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, we have therefore that, by the intermediate value theorem, $\exists c\in[0,x_0]$ such that $f(c)=y$, or, more appropriately, $\exists c\in[0,x_0]$ such that $\sqrt{y}=c$. This completes the proof.

Of course I am biased, since this is my own proof, and therefore believe the proof to be correct. However, the solution bank which I am using to verify this proof has used a different technique (which I will disclose if I am so prompted), so I was hoping someone could verify the accuracy of this proof. Any responses are appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The proof looks just fine.

I guess I would say that you don't actually need to apply the fact that $x^2 \to +\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$ in order to get the value of $x_0$ that you need. You can just take $x_0 = \max\{y,1\}$ and it follows that $f(x_0) \ge y$.

Comment: I like this idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My old professors would probably accept this proof, but at the same time accuse you of killing a fly with a sledgehammer.  You're not only making an appeal to IVT but also to the fact that $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous.

By contrast, a proof without IVT would have fewer moving parts.  You just need to note that given $x\in\mathbb R^+$ that the set $\{y\in\mathbb R^+\mid y^2>x\}$ is non-empty and bounded below.  Therefore that set has an infimum by the construction of the real numbers, which is in fact what we define as $\sqrt x$.

---

Edit: it was pointed out in comments that you were actually *ordered* to kill a fly with a sledgehammer.  In that case, you get bonus points from me for using $f(x)=x^2$ as your function instead of $f(x)=\sqrt x$.  Now, if you'll excuse me, I'm off to lament the state of real analysis education....

Comment: The question says that OP was asked to prove it USING the IVT. (I agree it's goofy, but so are lots of things...)

Comment: @JohnHughes Ah, so it does.

Comment: Thanks for this, humorous and educational! +1

Comment: I dunno, I can easily imagine that after having proved that square roots exist by another method, such as directly from the completeness axiom, one might well want to use the same example as the very first exercise in applying the IVT, especially in preparation for more substantial applications of the IVT such as existence theorems for roots of general polynomials.

Comment: One needs some practice in finding appropriate intervals --- for this post, the interval with endpoints $f(0)=0$ and $f(x_0)=x_0^2$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Fair enough.  I suppose I would prefer if it were finding $y=x^x$ or $y=x+\sin x$ or something where you actually **need** the tool you just developed, but I see where you're coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to prove that $x^2 = l$. Consider $f(x) = x^2$ , There exists a k > 0 such that $f(k) > l$. Don't believe me? if $l$ > 0, choose $k = l$. If $l<0$, choose $k = 1$.

So, we now have $ f(0) < l < f(k) $ because $l$ is a positive number but lower than some number $k$. By IVT, there is some number x in $[0,k]$ such that $f(x) = l$. Or $x^2 = l$ which is exactly what we need.